# How to configure docker to use redis with celery

Tags: django, docker, redis, celery

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: rd01
    ports:
     - '6379:6379'

  webapp:
    image: webapp
    container_name: wa01
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis


  celery:
    build: .
    container_name: cl01
    command: celery -A server worker -l info
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

I also don't feel I understand links and depends_on, I tried different combinations.

Celery cannot connect to redis. I get the following error -

```
[2018-08-01 13:59:42,249: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
```

I believe I have set broker URLs correctly in settings.py in my django application (webapp image)

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379/0' 
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
```

What is the right way to dockerize a django project with celery and redis? TIA.

### EDITS

#### celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'server.settings')

app = Celery('server')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

[This is my django  project](https://nofile.io/f/JKWyGqg2pvY/server.zip) to it's simplest form to reproduce the error.

Comment: can you add your `celery` configuraion settings?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge: Are you talking about celery.py?

Comment: yeah..please do add it

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge I've added it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to add the **`redis url`** while initialize the **`Celery`** classas,

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'server.settings')

app = Celery('server', broker='redis://redis:6379/0') # Change is here <<<<
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

### UPDATE

[After a long discussion]
Change your `docker-compose.yml` as

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: rd01

  webapp:
    build: .
    container_name: wa01
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis


  celery:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    container_name: cl01
    command: celery -A server worker -l info
    links:
      - redis
```

and `Dockerfile` as

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN mkdir /webapp
WORKDIR /webapp
COPY . /webapp
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

Comment: This didn't solve it. I feel the problem is with the way I configured `docker-compose.yml`. Because it worked fine locally. Like, without using docker.

Comment: The error in your question `Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//:` means you are trying to connect to `ampq` brocker.

Comment: It still gives the same error. I feel celery is not using the right config file or whatever inside docker. Without docker it is able to identify redis broker url correctly.

Comment: how do you are running the docker-compose?

Comment: `docker-compose up`

Comment: I'm sorry I can't do that. Also It's too big. I can share specific parts of the project. Do you know what you're looking for?

Comment: try use `--build` flag as   **`docker-compose up --build`**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177221/discussion-between-sp-and-jerin-peter-george).